# How do I do make a small box

Tags: android, android-activity

Sorry for beginning a noob but how do are do this with a small Activity/box where you can still see the background like in the image below. Are there any examples? Any help would be awesome. Thanks

[image: Small box]

Comment: This is a dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Ah thanks so much. Can they me made on top of fragments or only activity's?

Comment: Fragments are always hosted within an activity, but basically, yes, they can appear "on top" of a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **Dialog**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

> A dialog is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this code in your activity in manifest file then it becomes dialog

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```